# What is the relationship between Kiran and Ramesh?

Tags: logical-deduction, family

The following statements describe eight members of the Pratap and Kiran families, listed by their given name and/or by their relationship to another family member.

> - Pratap's wife's sister's husband's mother's son is Jayesh's cousin's
>     father.
> - Sunita's grand-daughter's cousin's father's sister-in-law is Suresh's
>     son-in-law's wife.

If Kiran has no children, **what is the relationship between Kiran and Ramesh?**

Comment: All of a sudden, regal family got introduced, by typo/auto-suggest feature of  a smart phone, perhaps ?! :-)

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with the implied gender of these names, it cannot be determined. I believe you also have a typo in there. Please review and specify what sex these people are.

Comment: @feelinferrety just use google images ;-)

Comment: It would be easier if Hindi versions of relations were used :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ramesh and Kiran are...

> Father and daughter, respectively

Family tree is as follows:

> [image: Kiran's Family Tree]